# Can an Interface contain a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't C# interfaces contain fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115114/why-cant-c-interfaces-contain-fields)

Hi all,

[Jon Skeet has answered to a question that Using a property is backed by a variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691899/properties-or-variables-in-c/5691915#5691915)

But properties in Interfaces are allowed in C#. Does that mean the interfaces in C# can contain a variable and how would the variable backed by the property will be handled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gishu - (+1) thanks for pointing to the right thread.

------------------------------------------------------
@Sandeep - In simple terms, an interface can contain method declarations only. Properties, events or indexers are variants of methods. Getter & setter in Properties are just variants of methods. Please refer "CLR via C#" OR "Essential .net Volume 1" for more details.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No.  An interface cannot contain a field.

An interface can declare a Property, but it doesn't provide any implementation of it, so there's no backing field.  It's only when a class implements an interface that a backing field (or automatic property) is needed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Though the property is syntactic sugar for get set method of a field, when used in Interface only get set methods are present excluding the field. Please correct me If I understood it wrong.

Comment: @Sandeep - A field doesn't have get/set methods.  A field is just an item of storage associated with a class.  A property is a member that is accessed in client code like a field, but allows execution of code to determine the value to be returned, or to do some processing when a value is set.  A property may be associated with one or more fields, but doesn't have to be.  An automatic property (`int Property { get; set; }`) is syntactic sugar for a property that just gets and sets a private backing field.

Comment: @Sandeep - An interface only specifies what client code should be able to do with an instance of a class that implements the interface.  It doesn't specify anything about how the class handle the interactions.  Therefore it just includes declarations for properties, method, events and indexers, with no implementation.  A Property declaration in a interface looks the same as an automatic property in a class, but there is no backing field and it doesn't actually do anything unless a class implements the interface.

Answer (score 36):

An interface can be a member of a namespace or a class and can contain signatures of the following members:

```
Methods

Properties

Indexers

Events
```

Properties can be declared on interfaces. The declaration takes the following form:
The accessor of an interface property does not have a body.

Thus, the purpose of the accessors is to indicate whether the property is read-write, read-only, or write-only.

Example:

```
// Interface Properties    
interface IEmployee
{
   string Name
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   int Counter
   {
      get;
   }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Employee: IEmployee 
{
   public static int numberOfEmployees;

   private int counter;

   private string name;

   // Read-write instance property:
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return name;
      }
      set
      {
         name = value;
      }
   }

   // Read-only instance property:
   public int Counter
   {    
      get    
      {    
         return counter;
      }    
   }

   // Constructor:
   public Employee()
   {
      counter = ++counter + numberOfEmployees;
   }
}
```

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass
{
   public static void Main()
   {    
      Console.Write("Enter number of employees: ");

      string s = Console.ReadLine();

      Employee.numberOfEmployees = int.Parse(s);

      Employee e1 = new Employee();

      Console.Write("Enter the name of the new employee: ");

      e1.Name = Console.ReadLine();  

      Console.WriteLine("The employee information:");

      Console.WriteLine("Employee number: {0}", e1.Counter);

      Console.WriteLine("Employee name: {0}", e1.Name);    
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Properties can be declared on an interface (not defined). But the accessor of an interface property **does not have** a body. Thus, **the purpose of the accessors** is to **indicate** whether the property is read-write, read-only, or write-only.

If you check out [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx) on this then you'll see that you **don't define** property in an interface instead the implementation is done by the inheriting Class.

```
interface IEmployee
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    int Counter
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public static int numberOfEmployees;

    private string name;
    public string Name  // read-write instance property
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    private int counter;
    public int Counter  // read-only instance property
    {
        get
        {
            return counter;
        }
    }

    public Employee()  // constructor
    {
        counter = ++counter + numberOfEmployees;
    }
}
```

So in the interface `IEmployee` the Syntax of properties looks like auto-implemented properties but they are just Indicating whether the property is `read-write`, `read-only`, or `write-only`, nothing more. Its the task of implementing class to do the Implementation and define the properties.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't mean that. The interface doesn't actually *contain* the property, either.

Remember than interface has to be *implemented* by a class in order for you to use it. An interface only defines a *contract*, meaning that any class that implements that interface will have all of the members defined by the interface. The interface doesn't actually have those members; it's more like a template. The instance of the class that *implements* the interface is the one that contains the property, and therefore the private backing field used for the property.

Interfaces can only define *signatures* for the following members:

- Methods
- Properties
- Indexers
- Events

Answer (score 2):

No, the interface is only the "contract". It's up to the implementing class implement the property; it may or may not use a variable to back it.

Comment: I think you're getting confused because the syntax of "auto-backed" properties is the same syntax of interface properties. In a class however, the compiler inserts the backing variable for you; ie. an auto-backed property is just syntactic sugar.