# C# - Advantages for using properties v. fields

Tags: c#, properties, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)
>   [Difference between Property and Field in C# .NET 3.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

Some time ago I inherited a C# web app wherein most class members that *could be fields* are defined as properties in one of the following two manners:

```
private Guid id;
public Guid Id
{
  get { return id; }
  set { id = value; }
}

public int someValue{ get; set; }
```

Namely, the getters/setters don't do anything other than ferry a value to/from a private field. In these cases, is there an advantage [or justification] for building these members out as properties vs. fields? And vice versa?

Would I be violating any unspoken rules or best practices by changing them to fields? Is there a notable performance difference -- for instance, incrementing `someValue` for a list of N objects one way or the other? (My current understanding is that field access is necessarily less complex [and efficient].)

Comment: As there isnt really one answer to this, it shouldn't really be a question here.  But the thought would be that if you ever needed to do validation of some sort, the property allows that easily in the getter and setter.  Where a field does not have that flexability.

Comment: There are a number of existing discussions on the merits of Properties vs Field - here is another one [Properties vs. Fields: Need help grasping the uses of Properties over Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069901/properties-vs-fields-need-help-grasping-the-uses-of-properties-over-fields)

Comment: OK. The comment from @Dustin Campbell on the selected answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5) is the only relevant justification I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly an OOP (Object Oriented Programming) notions: Encapsulation
You can view a brief description here;

[WikiPedia entry on Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

One of the possible uses is for example when trying to assign a value, to call a function to validate this new value. For example:

```
private Guid id;
public Guid Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set
    { 
        if (checkValue(value)==true)
        {
            id = value;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. I understand what encapsulation *can* be used for. The question is, in cases where the encapsulation *isn't* doing anything special, isn't it just unnecessarily overhead (and code)?

Comment: Encapsulation should only be used when you can predict that your class will be used/extended by other class and you need to protect your code . Normally this is about 80% of the times.