# What does the Auto Property give me over a simple Field?

Tags: c#

To be clear, I'm not asking for the [Difference between a field and a property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/979621).

Assuming I have just a basic auto-property, with no other access modifiers, what is the difference / advantage of having this:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

over this:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title;
}
```

To the client code using `Book`, it makes no difference: reads and writes are still done to `Book.Title`.

What benefits does the Auto Property offer over the simplistic Field?

Comment: @abatishchev: Not a duplicate. The answer to this very particular case isn't covered in that QA.

Comment: Hurry up, the boss tells you that now you need to make `Book` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so they can use it in an MVVM framework. Which is easier to modify? Which one would (potentially) break code?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields

Comment: I agree that question is not a duplicate of this question.  However, there are many duplicates of that question which are a duplicate of this question.  How about [Property(with no extra processing) vs public field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1272521/150605), [Advantages for using properties v. fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14651533/150605), or, maybe best of all, [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/150605)?  (Those questions explicitly define a backing field for their property, but are otherwise the same.)

Comment: @RonBeyer: I get that the auto-property is a safe design choice for future implementations without breaks. What I was really interested in is the difference it makes in the world of C# -- what is possible with auto-properties over and above the field. The links from BACON's answer shed a lot of light. Thanks!

Comment: Databinding uses properties not fields

Comment: It isn't just a "safe design choice", if you were given a request like that from your employer changing the field to a property is a breaking change for referenced libraries (even if they don't do anything other than `Book.Title = "xyz"`. Either way the biggest advantage I know of is the ability to set breakpoints, so you can see who is modifying the value and when.

Comment: @SNag: sure, reopened. I don't like the accepted answer there but others cover your question pretty much. Correct me if not.