# Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<ob>' to 'Generic.List<cdsworkflows>' nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by, generic-list

I have the below classes

```
public class cdsworkflows
{
    public string WorkflowName;
    public string ActionGroup;
}  

public class cdssystems
{
    public string cdsSystemName;
    public List<cdsmodules> listModules;
}

public class cdsmodules
{
    public string moduleName;
    public List<cdsworkflows> listWorkflows;
}
```

I am pushing the values to the above Objects from a table with all these data as below. I am getting error in "select new" that:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<cdsworkflows>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<cdsworkflows>`. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Also if you see the last line `ActionGroup = grpWorkflows.Count().ToString()` I want to assign the value and not the count. How to do that.

```
List<cdssystems> results =
    (from SPListItem item in myItemsList
     group item by item["Systems"]
     into grp
     select new cdssystems()
     {
         cdsSystemName = grp.Key.ToString(),
         listModules =
            from item in grp
            group item by item["Modules"]
            into grpModules
            select new cdsmodules()
            {
                moduleName = grpModules.Key.ToString(),
                listWorkflows =
                    from item in grpModules
                    group item by item["Workflows"]
                    into grpWorkflows
                    select new cdsworkflows()
                    {
                        WorkflowName = grpWorkflows.Key.ToString(),
                        ActionGroup = grpWorkflows.Count().ToString()
                    }
            }
     }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to assign the value and not the count. How to do that.*?

Comment: Actually i have item["ActionGroup"] in the collection. Thats basically the leaf node. I want to assign that value to ActionGroup.

Comment: See update of answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model classes contain properties of type `List<T>` but in your nested queries you do not add `ToList()` to the projection so it creates an `IEnumerable<T>` and therefore the error:

For `listWorkflows`: change to:

```
listWorkflows = (from item in grpModules
                 group item by item["Workflows"] into grpWorkflows
                 select new cdsworkflows
                 {
                    WorkflowName = grpWorkflows.Key.ToString(),
                    ActionGroup = grpWorkflows.Count().ToString()
                 }).ToList()
```

*Same idea for cdsmodules*

For the second part of the question of *I want to assign the value and not the count* change to:

```
 ActionGroup = string.Join(", ", grpWorkflows.Select(i => i["ActionGroup"]))
```

---

Also:

1. please refer to C# naming conventions: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions), [dotFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards)
2. I suggest that if you define your fields as `public` have them as [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). See this for some reference: [Properties vs. Fields: Need help grasping the uses of Properties over Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3069901/6400526)

Comment: Thanks Gilad. But how to project toList on select will the below works? (select new cdsworkflows()
                                                                                       {
                                                                                           WorkflowName = grpWorkflows.Key.ToString(),
                                                                                           ActionGroup = grpWorkflows.Count().ToString()
                                                                                       }).ToList()

Comment: Sure this is just for a POC. Yes will do all the suggestions once the dev starts. Thanks a lot bro.