# how to add object directly to nested ienumerable collection object group by Error- Cannot convert List to Collection

Tags: c#, nested, ienumerable, generic-list

Hi I have created few nested iEnumerable implemented classes.
CDSWorkflowCollection
CDSModuleCollection
CDSSystemCollection

Below are my Classes

```
  public class cdssystems
{
    public string cdsSystemName;
    public CDSModuleCollection listModules;

}


 public class cdsmodules
{
    public string moduleName;
    public CDSWorkflowCollection listWorkflows;
    }
 class cdsdelgate
{
    private string delgateName;
    private DateTime fromDate;
    private DateTime toDate;
    private string functionElement;
    private CDSSystemCollection cdsSystemsList;
    private string cdsComments;
    private string JobTitle;

}

   public class cdsworkflows
{
    public string WorkflowName;
    public string ActionGroup;

}

  class CDSWorkflowCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable<cdsworkflows>
{
    private List<cdsworkflows> cdsWorkflowList;
    private readonly object syncObject = new object();

    public CDSWorkflowCollection(IEnumerable<cdsworkflows> cdsWorkflowList)
        : base()
    {
        this.cdsWorkflowList = new List<cdsworkflows>(cdsWorkflowList);
    }

    public IEnumerator<cdsworkflows> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.cdsWorkflowList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.cdsWorkflowList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        if ((array.Rank != 1) || ((this.Count + index) > array.Length))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        int count = 0;

        foreach (cdsworkflows cssWorkflow in this.cdsWorkflowList)
        {
            array.SetValue(cssWorkflow, count++);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cdsWorkflowList.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return this.syncObject;
        }
    }
}

class CDSSystemCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable<cdssystems>
{
    private List<cdssystems> cdsSystemList;
    private readonly object syncObject = new object();

    public CDSSystemCollection(IEnumerable<cdssystems> cdsSystemList)
        : base()
    {
        this.cdsSystemList = new List<cdssystems>(cdsSystemList);
    }
```

//Rest of the code here
}

```
 class CDSDelegateCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable<cdsdelgate>
{
    private List<cdsdelgate> cdsDelegateist;
    private readonly object syncObject = new object();

    public CDSDelegateCollection(IEnumerable<cdsdelgate> cdsDelegateList)
        : base()
    {
        this.cdsDelegateist = new List<cdsdelgate>(cdsDelegateList);
    }
```

//Rest of the code here
}

No i want to add objects to the class using group by and my code goes like below

```
   var results = (from SPListItem item in myItemsList
                                    group item by item["Systems"]
                                        into grp

                                        select new cdssystems()
                                        {
                                            cdsSystemName = grp.Key.ToString(),
                                            listModules = (from item in grp
                                                          group item by item["Modules"] 
                                                              into grpModules
                                                              select new cdsmodules()
                                                              {
                                                                  moduleName = grpModules.Key.ToString(),
                                                                  listWorkflows = (from item in grpModules
                                                                                  group item by item["Workflows"]
                                                                                      into grpWorkflows
                                                                                      select new cdsworkflows()                                                                                             
                                                                                       {                                                                                          

                                                                                           WorkflowName = grpWorkflows.Key.ToString(),
                                                                                           ActionGroup = grpWorkflows.FirstOrDefault()["ActionGroup"].ToString()
                                                                                       }                                                                                      
                                                                                       ).ToList()
                                                              }).ToList()


                                        }).ToList();
```

I am getting Error in ToList() saying

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'CDS.BusinessObjects.CDSWorkflowCollection'

I know the parm expects a collection and i am passing List. How to pass the collection. Please help

Comment: Like the error states, you would have to assign it to a `new CDSWorkflowCollection([your lambda expression that returns .ToList()])`. Why would you want to create your own collection type though? I strongly recommend against it, there are plenty of good generic alternatives included in the framework.

Comment: could you please elaborate. how to set the objects using lamda within te collection preojection

Comment: Not sure how else to explain it, you have to wrap your projection in your constructor. You decided you wanted to use your own type so now you must adhere to that. You can't define your own type and then assign something else to it. The error message really is self explanatory.

Comment: You never did answer my question though. Why are you defining your own collection types? I seriously doubt you need to, show that code. If you can get rid of those types then your projection assignments will work just fine.

Comment: Try to use cast instead calling ToList(). For example, replace your first ToList() on 'as CDSWorkflowCollection'.

Comment: I have done it before without hacing a iEnumerable implementation just like this and it worked fine.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007095/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-ienumerableob-to-generic-listcdsworkflows. But i am finding it difficult to control my collection or further LINQ expreessions hence used my own collection with ienumerable implemnted.

Comment: `But i am finding it difficult to control my collection or further LINQ expreessions hence used my own collection with ienumerable implemnted` <= Why? I have been coding for decades and **rarely** ever see a need to create your own generic collection types. Share your collection code, I am willing to bet it can easily be refactored.

Comment: @AndreiS. - That will result in a `null` value being assigned. A `CDSWorkflowCollection` is not the same as `List<cdsworkflows>` and you can't cast between the 2 types.

Comment: Why i did is to use where clause once the main collection is been set. How i can do a where without implementing the iEnumerable. What i have above is the main classes. What i need is once the objects get filled i want to apply a shere clause in the cdsModulecollection to filter objects only with a cdsmodule name say 'Module1'

Comment: You mean there is no other code to `CDSWorkflowCollection` ? The reason I ask is because you did not include a closing `}` on that type (or the other collection types while I am at it). If that is the case delete that type and replace all the reference types with `List<cdsworkflows>` or `IList<cdsworkflows>` or `ICollection<cdsworkflows>`. I usually just use `List<cdsworkflows>` but it can depend on the situation.

Comment: It only has the iEnumerable implementation  - Edited above. Its the same for all the collections.

Comment: The answer is get rid of those types, they are useless... they add nothing of value. I don't know what else to tell you because this is the same thing I have written over 3 times now. Good luck.

Comment: One last question. If i get rid of the type CDSWorkflowCollection how can i make use of iEnumerable  extension methords?. I am sorry if i bug you with silly question may be to you!

Comment: All .net framework generic collection types and interfaces implement `IEnumerable<T>`, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your custom collection types and use the Generic ones from the .net framework instead. You can use `List<T>`, `IList<T>`, or `ICollection<T>`. There is *almost* never a need to write your own collection implementation(s).

```
public class cdsmodules
{
    public string moduleName;
    public CDSWorkflowCollection listWorkflows;
}
```

becomes

```
public class cdsmodules
{
    public string moduleName { get; set; }
    public List<cdsworkflows> listWorkflows  { get; set; }
}
```

---

You should also follow proper visibility guidelines by never exposing fields directly. Instead use a property with a `get;set;` accessor. Fields should almost always be scoped as `private` or `protected`.