# Is it a bad practice to replace every field in a class with a private property?

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions

I tend to use private properties instead of private fields because they can be extended if necessary, so most of my model classes look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
         this.Name = name;
    }

    private string Name { get; set; }
    private ISomeInterface SomeInterface { get; set; }
    private bool IsSomething { get; set; }

    public void Method(int parameter) { ... }
}
```

In other words, I usually replace private fields by private properties. Even inside the class context, properties are used, not fields. Most of them are auto-properties. Often I found out that my classes have no private fields at all (well, only the automatic backing fields for automatic properties).

I found this useful if you want to change the behavior (fields don't allow such flexibility).

I would like to know it this is a bad practice.

- If it is a bad practice: WHY?
- If it's not: do you think that I should use the "this" keyword inside the class to improve legibility?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you have a reasonable excuse for doing this, sure, it's acceptable.

Comment: Renamed all your instances of "variable" to "field" for correctness.

Comment: It seems acceptable to me, but I'm afraid I'm breaking some rule here. I would like that somebody could tell me if it's going to cause me problems or if this practice is disregarded.

Comment: What do you consider 'flexibility'? I consider it bad practice to implement stuff you might never use, but who am I.

Comment: There is a very good answer of Eric Lippert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3310469/3523746. But, I agree with Sergey Berezovskiy, if you need to just just a peace of data, it's better to use fields. But sometimes in cases Lippert showed, it's useful to have properties

Answer (score 2):

That might be a matter of preference, but I don't like an idea of usage private properties instead of private fields:

- There is very useful [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle which states not to do stuff which *might* be helpful in the future. Usually classes should not be like huge monsters, and you will be able very quickly wrap field into property when you will need it.
- It's part of internal class implementation which you can change anytime without breaking clients of your class (very different story  with public properties and fields - usually its better to use properties, even if you don't need to have some additional logic now).
- As @dcastro pointed, there might not be any performance hit, but without compiler optimizations private fields have better performance than properties (which are methods).
- Naming. I like to have private fields named with underscore, e.g. `_name` which allows me quickly distinguish between private and public members of class.

Sometimes I use private properties when I need some additional actions to be performed when I set some variable, or when value is computed based on other values, or when value is lazy-loaded. But when I do use, then I clearly see that something is happening there. That is very useful. If all fields would be properties, I would not have that hint.

Comment: Regarding your third point: afaik, there's a very high chance calls to auto-implemented properties will be inlined.

Comment: I don't see how either one is relevant.  Whether or not it's part of the internal implementation has nothing to do with whether or not it's a good idea.  For the second, YAGNI only goes so far - trivial implementations (such as defaults for parameters, fields vs properties, etc) can go either way.  And as @dcastro said for the third.

Comment: @dcastro agree (actually I consider performance only when I have problems with it), but it also thing which worth noting here

Comment: @Bobson its big difference when you have public property or public field. If you change field to property, then API of class will change. That's why I mentioned importance of *internal* implementation. Also I don't understand your comment about YAGNI

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy The question is about **private** properties. The public API doesn't change.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - Yes, when they're public it matters, but we're specifically discussing *private* implementations.  It's very true that you can change it without breaking anything, but that doesn't have anything to do with it being a good or bad idea.  Likewise, for YAGNI, choosing to implement it as a property *just in case* you need to add more to the getter/setter some day (instead of a field) is so trivial that YAGNI is irrelevant.  **Basically, your advice is good, but utterly irrelevant to the point you are trying to make.**

Comment: @SuperJMN yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about.