# What is the difference between {get; set;}, {get; private set;} and {get;}?

Tags: c#, class, private, getter-setter, public

I am new to C#, but I have used `{get; set;}` and found this `{get; private set}` and this `{get;}` in some earlier set of code written by someone else.

What does this exactly mean? What is the difference between `{get; set;}` and `{get; private set;}` and `{get;}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any reasons to use private properties in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310186/are-there-any-reasons-to-use-private-properties-in-c)

Answer (score 23):

When you write

```
public int MyProperty {get; set;}
```

both getter an setter have accessibility of `MyProperty`, which is `public` in this case. When you write

```
public int MyProperty {get; private set;}
```

only the getter remains `public`, while the setter becomes `private`. This approach is used to make properties that can be written only from inside of the class.

New version of C# gives you a closely related construct

```
public int MyProperty {get;}
```

which lets you make your property read-only. This is similar to `{get;private set;}` but in addition it restricts all assignments of `MyProperty` to the constructor of its containing class.