# Is there any reason to use field over automatic property?

Tags: c#

I know the benefits of using properties: bigger flexibility, easier changes, more convenient than methods, you can use them in interfaces etc. There are so many advantages that I never use fields (only automatic properties) and at this point I wonder if I'm doing right. Maybe there are some situation where instead of

```
private int Variable { get; set; }
```

I should use

```
private int variable;
```

Even when I don't need it to be a property, I use automatic properties in case it would change and then it will be to late to change it painlessly.

Comment: Since in your example above, the property is `private`, a better question might be is there any reason to use a property when it's marked private? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310186/are-there-any-reasons-to-use-private-properties-in-c discusses this

Comment: Mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties

Comment: @ADyson No, these are arguments for using properties over fields. I wonder if there's opposite situation when you should use field over property. As now I use properties for everything and never use fields and I wonder is it ok.

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule see above please

Comment: @wozar I'd say that (by simple logical deduction) it's fine to use fields in any situations not mentioned as a scenario where you ought to use a property. The thing with fields is, they're just variables which happen to be attached to a class, rather than declared in a method. Unlike properties they don't really have any interesting extra features where you could make a positive case that it'd be an advantage. IMO you can just assume you could/should use them anytime that it wouldn't be a disadvantage to not use a property.

Comment: If you are using (non-constant) properties, you are *also* always using fields, albeit fields the compiler generates for you. There have been scenarios in the past where you were required to make a field explicit (because you needed to apply an attribute to them, or because you needed to initialize a readonly field lazily) but there has been a steady introduction of syntax to make this unnecessary. It is still worth keeping in mind that for some scenarios (as in serialization or other low-level bit groveling) only the fields may be considered and not the properties.

Comment: @wozar a property is a function it can be overridden, hide and apply polymorphy to it. Only thing is you can not use  for "ref" or "out" parameter

Comment: @ADyson So using properties in any situation, as I do now, is perfectly fine. Good to know. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: `ref`/`out` is a good point -- an important thing you cannot do with a property is use it as an argument to `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and other atomic primitives that need `ref` parameters. These are fairly niche uses, but important ones. On the other hand, they're also easy to spot.

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule Yes, this is worth keeping in mind. I also noticed if type of your property is struct you can't change just one field - you have to assign a new struct (because `get` returns a copy of value type variable)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for pointing that case. I hope I will remember this when I will be advanced enough to understand case you mentioned :)

Comment: @wozar one more  thing about property is you can inject dependency through a property